# Residual Income Valuation with Term Structure

Tags: finance-mathematics, valuation, math

I'm implementing a residual income model (RIM) to value stocks as described by Ohlson.

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c0a5/4ef41311951fe406d15cd7d7ce19502cdc7c.pdf

The key to this model is described on page 330:

"Equating RIV to PVED depends only on a simple scheme that requires no reference to economic or accounting concepts...

$$0 = y_0 + R^{-1}(y_1-Ry_0) +R^{-2}(y_2 - Ry_1)+...$$

I've seen this implemented with time-varying rates once before in a recent article (note that they use $coe_t$ (cost of equity at time t):

https://www.fondazioneoiv.it/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Residual-Income-Model.pdf

However, I wonder if the scheme presented in this work requires an adjustment, since introducing a term structure of rates turns $R$ into $R_t$, and the telescoping equation above does not necessarily equal 0. Does anyone have any insight on what the adjustment term (if necessary) should be? If it's not necessary, then what exactly does the remainder represent?

---

EDIT:

I figured out the math. It is still possible to use RIM (and AEG for that matter) with time-varying rates. This is the classic presentation of RIM

$$V_0 = \sum\limits_{t=0}^{\infty} \frac{D_t + BV_t - (1+k)BV_{t-1}}{(1+k)^t} $$

But in the modified version, $k$ in the numerator needs to be the forward rate $f$ at year t while the $k$ in the denominator needs to be the spot rate $s$ for year t.

$$V_0 = \sum\limits_{t=0}^{\infty} \frac{D_t + BV_t - (1+f_{t,1})BV_{t-1}}{(1+s_t)^t} $$

This still yields the telescoping time series that is equal to 0.

Comment: Very good. Looks like you solved your problem.